# how to call Handsontable's method

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I'm new in Handsontable.

I want to call Handsontable's method such as getData or selectCell. I have already tried out what the [documentation](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0-beta6/Core.html#addHook) is saying but it doesn't work.

Below is my JavaScript (jQuery) code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var test;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'accounting/ajax/ajaxLoadForViewAccount.php',
    datatype: 'script',
    data: {
        tbname:tbname
    },
    success: function (response) {

        test = JSON.parse(response);

        var data = new Array();
        var headerName = new Array();
        var i=0;

        for(i=0;i<test.room_num.length;i++){
            var obj = {room_num:test.room_num[i],rental_fee:test.rental_fee[i]};
            data.push(obj);
            headerName[i] = test.room_num[i];
        }

        var container = document.getElementById('example');
        var hot;

        hot = new Handsontable(container, {
            data: data,
            colWidths: [80, 80],
            rowHeaders: headerName,
            colHeaders: ['room_num','rental_fee']
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }
});


$('#submit').click(function () {
    $('#example').append("<p>Testtttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</p>");

    $('#example').handsontable('setDataAtCell',1,1,'10000');
    alert('test');
    });
});
```

According to my code, after I click the submit button the `example` div is appended with "Testtttttttttttttttttttt" that means `$('example')` selector should work fine. In addition the `'test'` alert also appears. However the method `setDataAtCell` doesn't work.

Comment: what happens after the append? also, you can just use `hot.setDataAtCell(1,1,'10000')` instead

Answer (score 1):

Consider always using the `hot` instance variable to access the instance. In your case:

```
hot.setDataAtCell(1,1,'10000')
```